# Maximum file size allowed by ASP.NET file upload Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, file-upload

I am using File upload control in ASP.Net, followed the below blogs approach.

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx

The 4MB default is set in machine.config, but you can override it in you web.config. For instance, to expand the upload limit to 20MB, you'd do this:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="20480" />
</system.web>
```

**Question:**
 Till what level(MAX size) i can increase the requested length and what will be performance impact on site if we allowed user to upload 50-60 MB files also.

Comment: Well the performance impact will be that every time someone uploads a massive file it will use that much bandwidth.....

Comment: it's around 2 GB for IIS 7 (but @Liam consideration about bandwidth is true). If you really need that...it's better to implement another interface for file uploading (for example using POSTs and custom browser extensions).

Comment: @Liam,@Adriano The application will be hosted on intranet and hence bandwidth available is more. But i want to restrict the user to some limit as if IIS is engaged in catering 100MB-200MB files the other users of website will get lower performance.

Comment: @Pratik not to mention the other users of your network! even on gigabit ethernet, you get 5 users uploading a 100Mb file, thats going to hurt!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'theoretical' max level for the `maxRequestLength` field is the max value for signed 32-bit integer data type (`Int32.MaxValue`).

However, you are going to have to test the upload in order to understand your performance.

EDIT:

From [a Microsoft support ticket](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=295626):

> Theoretically, the maximum file upload size is fairly large. However,
>   because of ASP.NET health monitoring, you cannot upload very large
>   files in ASP.NET. The ASP.NET worker process has a virtual address
>   space of 2 gigabytes (GB). However, the ASP.NET worker process only
>   uses a little more than 1 GB because of health monitoring and memory
>   fragmentation.
>
> During the upload process, ASP.NET loads the whole file in memory
>   before the user can save the file to the disk. Therefore, the process
>   may recycle because of the memoryLimit attribute of the processModel
>   tag in the Machine.config file. The memoryLimit attribute specifies
>   the percentage of physical memory that the ASP.NET worker process can
>   exhaust before the process is automatically recycled. Recycling
>   prevents memory leaks from causing ASP.NET to crash or to stop
>   responding.
>
> Additionally, other factors play a role in the maximum file size that
>   can be uploaded. These factors include available memory, available
>   hard disk space, processor speed, and current network traffic. With
>   regular traffic of files being uploaded, Microsoft recommends that you
>   use a maximum file size in the range of 10 to 20 megabytes (MB). If
>   you rarely upload files, the maximum file size may be 100 MB.
>
> Note You can upload files that are larger than 100 MB in ASP.NET.
>   However, Microsoft recommends that you follow the maximum file upload
>   sizes that are mentioned in this article. To determine more precise
>   file sizes, perform stress testing on computers that are similar to
>   the ones that will be used in production.

Comment: -1, no, it's expressed **in KB** and the limit is much lower (2,097,152 KB = 2 GB)

Comment: @Adriano I didn't mention anything about the qualification of the number.  However, it is good to know that it is KB, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @DavinTryon The explaination is very useful in justifying the limits of ASP.net file upload control. Thanks a lot.