# How to upload upto 8 GB of data on network server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, file-upload

i have to upload 8GB data file on network storage server through my mvc3 web application ?
currently i can upload upto 50 mb file but i want to upload upto 8 GB data file.

Comment: How about using some external uploader like QQ uploader?? (But I don't how to implement QQ uploader in MVC, if you are interested, you can do some research about this)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [HttpRequest.GetBufferlessInputStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.getbufferlessinputstream(v=vs.110).aspx).
This discussion is interesting as well 
[Maximum file size allowed by ASP.NET file upload Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248934/maximum-file-size-allowed-by-asp-net-file-upload-control).