# ASP.NET 4.0 C# File Upload multiple files using JQuery maxRequestLength needs to be over 4gb

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, http

I need to somehow do a work around with an asp.net File Uploader so it can take more than 4gb of multiple files.  Is there any way to set the web.config or write a C# function that just bypasses the Max Limit of File space that is used by ASP.Net and IIS 7?  I tried to look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195568.aspx but I have no idea how to use the function.  Please help, anyone with information about a work around that would be great since microsoft has put limits I'm guessing there has to be something out there that can bypass the limitations.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248934/maximum-file-size-allowed-by-asp-net-file-upload-control

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `maxRequestLength` is an variable of `Int32` type (maximum value is `2147483647` - `0x7FFFFFFF`)

But if you want to extend maxRequestLangh for your application then you can do that by adding couple of attributes to your `httpRuntime` in web.config:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="<size in bytes>" executionTimeout="<timeout in seconds>" />
```

Here is an example (2 gb of max lenght and about 10 minutes of timeout):

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="600" />
```

Also you need to add `security` part to `system.webServer`:

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Might be useful:

[**MSDN: maxAllowedContentLength**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689462%28VS.90%29.aspx)

[**MSDN: httpRuntime Element**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[**Large File Upload in IIS**](http://ajaxuploader.com/large-file-upload-iis-asp-net.htm)

[**Fixing File Upload Size Limit in IIS 7**](http://www.cyprich.com/2008/06/19/fixing-file-upload-size-limit-in-iis-7/)